# Existence of request.account when wrapping passport.authorize in anonymous function

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Looking for insight as to why the attribute `req.account` -- which is created during the call of [`passport.authorize()`](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authorize/) -- **does** exist for the downstream middleware `callback.bind()` in the first case, but **not** the second?

First case:

```
auth.get(
  `/callback/${strategy.name}`,
  passport.authorize(strategy.name, {
    failureRedirect: '/v1/auth/error',
    successRedirect: '/v1/users/me'
  }),
  callback.bind(null, strategy)
)
```

Second case:

```
auth.get(
  `/callback/${strategy.name}`,

  // primary difference here: wrapping passport.authorize in function
  function(req, res, next){
   if (strategy.name == 'google') {
     passport.authorize(strategy.name, {
       failureRedirect: '/error',
       successRedirect: '/users/me'
     })

     // and then calling next()
     next()
   }
  },
  callback.bind(null, strategy)
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult for me to test, but I would try returning your call to `passport.authorize`, since that is what is essentially happening in case 1.

As you commented, the trick is getting `next` to fire at the right time. (And don't forget to call `next()` in an else clause.)

**Edit:**
I took another shot at it, wrapping it in an IIFE. Hoping this replicates what happens in your case 1.

```
auth.get(
  `/callback/${strategy.name}`,

  // primary difference here: wrapping passport.authorize in function
  function(req, res, next){
    if (strategy.name == 'google') {
      (passport.authorize(strategy.name, {
        failureRedirect: '/error',
        successRedirect: '/users/me'
      })(req, res, next)
    }
    else next() // ??
  },

  callback.bind(null, strategy)
)
```

Comment: Appreciate the response, but no dice.  When adding `return` -- even with callback -- it hangs, suggesting to me it never fires `next()`.  Furthermore, I had thought that middleware could modify/manipulate state without returning anything, but passing along, but perhaps I have that wrong...

Comment: I think you're right about the callback. I believe the trick is sending `req, res, next` to passport. See code update with IIFE. That might work.